# Adding random slopes before or after backward elimination of fixed effects?

Tags: random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I have a few questions about doing a linear mixed-effects model in R using the package lme4.
I have reaction time data with 3 fixed factors and random effects for subjects and items. I want to have a "maximal" random-effects structure as recommended by [Barr et al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749596X12001180), 2013 (J Mem Lang 68, 255, [PDF](http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~rlevy/papers/barr-etal-2013-jml.pdf)).
I've performed the following steps in this order:

1. I set up an initial model with all fixed effects and interactions and random intercepts for items and subjects (but no random slopes)
2. There was stress in the residuals plot, so I excluded data points with residuals exceeding +/- 2.5 SDs
3. I performed backward elimination of the fixed effects using log-likelihood ratio tests
4. I then added random slopes (both by-subjects and by-items) for all fixed effects and interactions, even for interaction terms that had been eliminated in step 3.

I have 2 questions about this:

- (A) Is it correct to first do backward elimination of fixed effects and then add the random slopes. Should it be the other way around?
- (B) Is step 4 correct, i.e. adding random slopes even for interaction terms that were eliminated in step 3?

I would appreciate any help on this as I couldn't find any information on this in the Barr et al.'s paper.

Comment: Selecting a model based on statistical tests is not valid.

Comment: Does it makes sense to have a random slope in your model? What is the nature of you data? I am actually afraid that most people reading that paper will just go ahead and add random slopes in every LME model they get their hands on just so they are part of the "in-crowd"...  If you are adamant about using backward elimination use at least an Information Criterion (eg. AICc) instead of a raw LR test (It is similar but not the same); I would argue cross-validation as a better choice. Finally, why are you docking a *perfectly good* dataset? Do you believe it's corrupted? What is its size?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, user11852. To answer your questions: (1) my impression was that backward elimination should always be done, at I've read many papers using linear mixed effects models that did this. Is this not necessary/desirable?  (2) my data set has about 700 observations  (3) the removal of data points with residuals exceeding +/- 2.5 SDs was done following the recommendation in a paper by Baayen & Milin (2010) entitled "Analyzing reaction times", about 2% of data points were affected by this

Comment: 1. It is not *unreasonable* to do backwards elimination but be it should be used with caution. Cross-validation (even something crude like *jack-knifing*) would probably put most picky people at better ease. In any case you want something **linguistically meaningful**. 2. I would not remove the data points unless they are obviously corrupted or something similar; B&M do that after examining the residual plots; are your residuals plots "bad"? Given 1/81 sample points in a Gaussian should be outside +/-2.5 SD, your residuals sound OK!

Comment: (Don't get me wrong; I have huge respect about Baayen's work (he also gives great feedback as a referee), anything he does though doesn't immediately apply to my/your work.)